# ADF: Pass dynamic Where Clause as a string with quotes

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a lookup that retrieves a few records from a SQL Server table containing server, database, schema, table name and a whole where clause. These values are passed to a copy data (within a ForEach) In the copy data i have tried to use two different Dynamic query statement, but I seem to get an error. And can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Values in table:

| SRC_SERVERNAME | SRC_DATABASE | SRC_SCHEMANAME | SRC_TABLENAME | SRC_WHERE_DATE_CLAUSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SQ01 | NAV | dbo | Company$Sales Invoice Header | where [Posting Date] >= '2021-01-01' |

Source setup:

[image]

Error for statement 1:

> A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'
> Incorrect syntax near '.'., SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,State=1,

Error for statement 2:

> A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'
> Incorrect syntax near '.'., SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,State=1,

Statement 1 (query):

```
SELECT *  
FROM @{item().SRC_SERVERNAME}.@{item().SRC_DATABASENAME}.@{item().SRC_SCHEMANAME}.@{item().SRC_TABLENAME},' ',@{item().SRC_WHERE_DATE_CLAUSE}
```

Statement 2 (dynamic query with concat):

```
@concat('select * from ',item().SRC_SERVERNAME,'.',item().SRC_DATABASENAME,'.',item().SRC_SCHEMANAME,'.',item().SRC_TABLENAME,' ',item().SRC_WHERE_DATE_CLAUSE)
```

Comment: Hi, In statement2, there is a dot (.) missing between database and schema name. Can you change it and try?

Comment: Hi, it was just a wrong typo. In the code I have had '.'. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your query.

- In the 4-part naming of SQL database, server name/database name/schema name/table name should be separated by **`‘.’`**.
- When you have space or other special characters in the name of server/database/schema/table, they should be embedded inside square braces `[]`.

  ```
  @concat('select * from [',item().SRC_SERVERNAME, '].[',item().SRC_DATABASENAME,'].[',item().SRC_SCHEMANAME,'].[',item().SRC_TABLENAME, '] ',item().SRC_WHERE_DATE_CLAUSE)
  ```

Comment: Hi, I have no issue connecting to the server. So when I add bracets, then I can't connect to the server/database etc. The following solution doesnt work, it already fail's with the connection

Comment: Okej, figured out my error. Har to change the Server name. Works fine now!